# Limit Words by a Certain Number of Words

Tags: php

need to know how to tracunate words by a number.I've searched all over the Google and yet all of them are not working by an unknown reason.

```
function trimtext($data, $limit) {
    //trim here
}

$test = 'This is a very very very long words here blablabla1 blablabla blablabla2  test';
echo trimtext($test, 10); //this should output 'This is a very very very long words here blablabla'
```

Comment: What is the expected output? The first 10 words if the `$limit` is 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `explode()` function to split the string. Then use `array_slice()` function to get required number of elements from the array. And finally use `implode()` function to join the array elements.

```
function trimtext($data, $limit) {
    $arr = explode(" ", $data);
    $new_arr = array_slice($arr, 0, $limit);
    return implode(" ", $new_arr);
}

$test = 'This is a very very very long words here blablabla blablabla blablabla  test';
echo trimtext($test, 10);
```

Output:

```
This is a very very very long words here blablabla
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: thanks! also, i've just figured out some bugs in my application that caused all the codes from google failed to work.

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan what are these *bugs*?

Comment: although i'm quite shame that i've to tell you this, but i've failed to have a good practice in my codes. just some human mistakes and messed up codes.. anyway thanks

Comment: Note that this will fail if you have multiple spaces or new lines between words, or have spaces before the first word: you will get less than 10 words as a result.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, just replace `explode()` with `preg_split()`, with pattern `/\s+/` to fix the issue trincot mentioned.

Comment: With the *preg_split* patch, the result will not have the same white space as the original string, newlines and tabs will be replaced by a single space. This might be an undesirable side-effect. Also, spaces at the start of the string will still leave you with 9 words instead of 10.

Comment: I agree, this solution doesn't cover all the boundary conditions, but OP's question was very straight forward and simple, hence the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With a regular expression this can be done in one call, to [*preg_replace*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$long_text = "This is a phrase that has 10 words in it. But 
              more text is following and should be ignored";

$first10 = preg_replace("/^(\s*(\S+\s+){0,9}\S+).*/s", '$1', $long_text);
```

The content of *$first10* will be:

> This is a phrase that has 10 words in it.

Here is what the regular expression does:

- `^`: match only at the start of the string, not anywhere else
- `\s*`: allow 0 or more spaces at the start
- `(...)`: capture group, whatever is matched is referenced later with *$1*
- `\S+`: one or more non-space characters (i.e. a word)
- `\s+`: one or more spaces
- `(...){0,9}`: match as many times as possible, up to 9 times.
- `.*`: anything else up until the end (as nothing else is specified after).
- `s`: the modifier after the slash dictates that the dot should also match new lines

Note that this will match with any string, as they all start with zero or more blanks, have zero or more words in it, and have zero or more characters following that.

The replacement is:

- `$1`: whatever was captured in brackets (the outer ones), thereby omitting whatever was matched by `.*`.

See it working in this [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/jU7nF0/1).

Note that this solution works correctly when:

- words are numbers;
- words are separated by more than one blank;
- words are separated by a line-break, tab, or other white-space;
- the sentence starts with blanks;

Comment: Put your `$1` inside single quotes, otherwise PHP will try to find a variable `$1`

Comment: @TareqMahmood, thanks for pointing that out. I replaced it, but I don't think it is really necessary. PHP does not try to find a variable when there are only digits following the *$*. At least with double quotes the code worked for me.

Comment: hmm, this solution looks more promising than my solution, plus it covers all the boundary conditions. +1 from my side. :)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative with `str_word_count` function:

```
$test = 'This is a very very very long words here blablabla blablabla blablabla  test';
function trimtext($text, $limit = 1) {
    if (empty($text)){
        return $text;
    }
    $words  = str_word_count($text, 1, '0123456789');
    $slice = (count($words) >= $limit)? array_slice($words, 0, $limit) : $words; 
    return implode(" ", $slice);
}
var_dump(trimtext($test, 10));
```

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan, `implode` function lets you to join elements with a string in ONE-dimensional arrays only http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Note that this will fail if you have words like "12" in it. They will be removed from the result. `str_word_count` is not suitable for this question.

Comment: @trincot, agreed, but I've added a simple workaround

Comment: Yes, but there is a fundamental problem where digits are only an example. Try with accented words like *déjà*, and you will get two words: *"d*" and *"j"*. It will be an impossible task to make `str_word_count` work with all this cases. Another example is punctuation. With *"Look!"*, the exclamation mark will be lost.

Comment: @trincot, you are talking about ideal perfect solution of words count. Of course, it will not cover all possible UTF-8 symbols. My solution is for lightweight cases. For ideal solutions I would use `preg_split`, `preg_replace`

Comment: It is not only UTF-8, but even the very common point at the end of a sentence, or commas. I agree completely, this is best solved with regular expressions.